# How to find the set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ that $A$ is the basic set for a given divisibility relation and a given HASSE-Diagram?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

How to find the set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ that $A$ is the basic set for the divisibility relation:

$R_A=_{def} \{(m,n) | m,n \in A \wedge m ~ \text{divides} ~ n \} \subseteq A \times A$

for the following HASSE-Diagram 
[image: 1]

Comment: I don't understand the question. First, why is there a node in the Hasse diagram labeled $A$? Is this the same as the set $A$, and if so, how do I make sense of that? Second, what is the definition of $R_A$ again? You write "$m,n\in A\land \frac{m}{n}$", but the last part $\frac{m}{n}$ is not a statement.

Comment: To the first question I have no answer because I also don't understand it why my prof labled this node with $A$.. The $\frac{m}{n}$ should mean, that every $m$ divides the $n$ in the relation $(m,n)$ 

Edit: Maybe it's a hexadecimal designation so like $9,A,B,C,D,E,F$

Comment: Ah, then I believe I understand. Are the colors for anything? Or just to make it look nice?

Comment: That's the next point which I don't understand, but i don't think it's for the nice looking beacuse my prof is more the pragmatic personality type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must've been tired the first time. Here's a new and simpler picture:

[image: Hasse]

Note that $6 = 2\cdot 3$, $15 = 3\cdot 5$, $25=5^2$, $30 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5$, $75 = 3\cdot 5^2$, $125 = 5^3$, and $750 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5^3$.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what you did there? And does $11.250$ or $ 33.750$ for the top node also work?

Comment: @fragant yeah, it would have worked, but I realise I made a mistake. We have that $125$ divides $375$, but there is no upwards path both $125$ to $375$, which violates the diagram. We can replace $375$ with just $75$.

Comment: @fragant What I did was to note that the number on the bottom node has to divide everything above it, which is why I chose $1$. The three nodes at the next lowest level do not divide into each other in any way, which is why I chose the first three primes $2$, $3$, and $5$. Now $2$ and $3$ has to divide some number (at the second blue node), and the only restriction is that $5$ doesn't divide it, and so on.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right.  Other question, do you think I have to represent the solution like: relation tuple $(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,6),(5,15),(6,25)...$ So every node has a relation to a number?

Comment: @fragant I don't know your professor, but I would give him the set $A = \{1,2,3,5,6,15,25,30,75,125,750\}$, and I would then include the diagram, since that is the simplest way of describing the partial order: If there is an upwards path from node $m$ to note $n$, then $m$ divides $n$,

Comment: @fragant you're welcome. :)